# SelectedValue remains = 1 in one routine, yet another similar routine works

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, gridview, entity-framework-6

Okay, I am absolutely stumped.  Here's what I mean:
Here's the ManageTeams.aspx.cs `BindTeams()` routine, which works perfectly:

```
public void BindTeams()
{
    using (var db = new SoccerDbContext())
    {
        int lId = 0;

        IQueryable<Team> teams = db.Teams;

        //if any league is selected, then filter below.  Do not run if first run.
        //if first run, the whole list is displayed.  This also happens on form reset.
        if (0 < Convert.ToInt32(drp_Leagues1.SelectedValue) && !firstRun) 
        {
            var leagueId = Convert.ToInt32(drp_Leagues1.SelectedValue);
            teams = teams.Where(t => t.CurrentLeagueId == leagueId);
            lId = leagueId;
        }
        lbl_Debug.Text = "1Sindex=" + drp_Leagues1.SelectedIndex.ToString() +
                       ", 2Sindex=" + drp_Leagues2.SelectedIndex.ToString() +
                       ", 1Svalue=" + drp_Leagues1.SelectedValue +
                       ", 2Svalue=" + drp_Leagues2.SelectedValue +
                       ", leagueId=" + lId +
                       ", firstRun=" + firstRun;
        grd_Teams.DataSource = teams.ToList();
        grd_Teams.DataBind();
    }
}
```

And the associated `Team.cs` class:

```
public class Team
    {
        public int TeamId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(100)]
        public string TeamName { get; set; }

        public DateTime DateEstablished { get; set; }

        //Navigation property -> Each team has many players
        public List<Player> Players { get; set; }

        //Navigation property -> Each team belongs to a specific league
        public League CurrentLeague { get; set; }

        //Foreignkey -> The associated LeagueId
        //[Required]
        [ForeignKey("CurrentLeague")]
        public int CurrentLeagueId { get; set; }

    }
```

And here's the ManagePlayers.aspx.cs `BindPlayers_byTeam()` routine, which **doesn't** work:

```
public void BindPlayers_byTeam()
{
    using (var db = new SoccerDbContext())
    {
        int tId = 0;
        IQueryable<Player> players = db.Players;

        //if any team is selected, then filter below.  Do not run if first run.
        //if first run, the whole list is displayed.  This also happens on form reset.
        if (0 < Convert.ToInt32(drp_Teams1.SelectedValue) && !firstRun)
        {
            var teamId = Convert.ToInt32(drp_Teams1.SelectedValue);
            players = players.Where(t => t.CurrentTeamId == teamId);
            tId = teamId;
        }
        lbl_Debug.Text = "Sindex=" + drp_Teams1.SelectedIndex.ToString() +
                         ", Svalue=" + drp_Teams1.SelectedValue +
                         ", teamId=" + tId +
                         ", firstRun=" + firstRun;
        grd_Players.DataSource = players.ToList();
        grd_Players.DataBind();
    }
}
```

And the associated `Player.cs` class (which is correctly written):

```
public class Player
   {
       public int PlayerId { get; set; }

       [Required]
       [MaxLength(100)]
       public string FullName { get; set; }

       public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }

       public DateTime LicenseDate { get; set; }

       public int TeamCount { get; set; }

       [ForeignKey("CurrentTeam")]
       public int CurrentTeamId { get; set; }

       public Team CurrentTeam { get; set; }
   }
```

The whole purpose of both Bind routines is to return a filtered list of teams/players with the same CurrentLeagueId/CurrentTeamId, respectively.  Between the two routines, there is no functional difference except the variable names, yet the `SelectedValue` value in the latter routine consistently returns a value of 1, when it should return a value consistent with the selected team on the dropdownlist. No matter what I select there, I always get value of 1! And hence the result I get:

[image: Concatenated screenshots of two tables]

The former routine doesn't have this problem and is functionally equivalent to the latter routine.  I've looked everywhere for any difference in the code to explain the anomaly, in the property box and in the markup.  I don't see what's wrong.  What could it be?

Again, this statement:

```
if (0 < Convert.ToInt32(drp_Leagues1.SelectedValue) && !firstRun) 
        {
            var leagueId = Convert.ToInt32(drp_Leagues1.SelectedValue);
            teams = teams.Where(t => t.CurrentLeagueId == leagueId);
            lId = leagueId;
        }
```

...is functionally equivalent to this other routine:

```
if (0 < Convert.ToInt32(drp_Teams1.SelectedValue) && !firstRun)
        {
            var teamId = Convert.ToInt32(drp_Teams1.SelectedValue);
            players = players.Where(t => t.CurrentTeamId == teamId);
            tId = teamId;
        }
```

...yet one works while the other doesn't.

Comment: Could it be `firstRun` is set after the first time it is run?

Comment: Doesn't matter. It's outside the influence that causes the seeming anomaly.

Comment: But... Barcelona is the first element in your dropdown.  Isn't Barcelona Id=1?  That seems to be the correct Id for Svalue.

Comment: @Scottie- I selected Fenerbahce, not Barcelona, then clicked the filter button.  Yet it returns to Barcelona, because SelectedValue = 1.

Comment: I assume this is WebForms. Make sure your dropdown list is populated at the "init" stage of the page lifecycle.

Comment: How are you initializing your DDL's

Comment: @jeyoung- yes, it's bind'ed (populated) in the Page_Load routine.

Comment: @friostro- I'm not sure.  You mean the ones in the references?  I'm not doing anything special to them.

Comment: where are you calling `BindPlayers_byTeam` and `BindTeams`?  In form_load and in dropdown_selectedindexchanged?

Comment: only bound once correct?  you have the binding wrapped in a `if( ! Page.IsPostBack )`

Comment: my strong guess is, you are not using `!IsPostBack` properly or not at all using while calling `BindTeams`

Comment: D'oh!  Forgot about (!PostBack)!  After putting that in, it works.  Thanks, guys.

Comment: Put it in an answer and I'll give you a bounty... @friosto or techspider

Comment: The better place to populate your controls is at the page initialization stage.

Comment: That's impractical; you cannot bind any data at that stage because controls haven't been initialized yet, and there's no guarantee that they'll be available for use at that stage.